# Symfony EasyAdminbundle: How to create an html tag datalist under an input field in new view

Tags: php, symfony

Have you an idea what would be the best way to implement the html tag datalist  under another html field ? I need to implement this in the new and edit view.

```
    {{ form_label(form.zip) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.zip) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.zip}} // this is an <input type="text"> field.
    //Here I would like to include an html <datalist> tag (which obviously is not a property of my entity rendered by the form)
```

The datalist will contain a huge list of zip code. more than 2000 elements. 
Something like this:

```
<datalist id="zip_france">
        <option data-zip="75000">Paris</option>
        <option data-zip="13000">Marseille</option>
        <option data-zip="34000">Montpelier</option>
        . . . . 2000 elements
</datalist>
```

Comment: What shall appear in the `<datalist>` element? A property of the entity that is not editable by the form itself?

Comment: (I edited my question).
Not a property of the entity. The datalist will contain a huge list of zip code. more than 2000 elements. 
Something likethis:
<datalist id="zip_belgium">
        <option data-zip="75000">Paris</option>
        <option data-zip="13000">Marseille</option>
        <option data-zip="34000">Montpelier</option>
        . . . . 2000 elements
</datalist>

Comment: Are you looking for the [`ChoiceFieldType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) ? You can extend it with a custom `form_theme` to be rendered as datalist.

Comment: Yes I think it will be a ChoicefieldType. But I'm not sure.

Comment: `datalist` is for suggestions aka. autocompletion. Is that what you really want? Or do you want the user to **definitely** choose one of the values out of this list? Then the `select` field would be semantically correct.

Comment: I will use this <datalist> field for suggestions of course.

Comment: Just for clarification ... the user would be allowed to enter something like "__I don't care__" into the field as a **valid** value for this `text` field / entity-property?

Comment: Yes. the user could enter any string.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to render these 2000+! entries directly into the html, possibly loading 2000+ entries from whatever storage you use? You might run into performance issues here. Have you considered using JavaScript-based "autocompletion" with a suggestion API endpoint instead of that huge prepopulated datalist?

Comment: I will implement the javascript based solution if I'm not able by overiding the EasyadminBundle form.

To be honnest I can implement this datalist like I want But when I overide the form in "new" view, the button "submit" of the overided form is not present. I think this problem appears because I forget to extend a twig block from the basic form template given by EasyAdminbundle.